# Determine SAP Document Type changes during the year

Tags: sap-erp, document-types

I'm doing internal assurance work, where my company wants to check if any Document type from table `T003` was changed during the year. They are looking to check if the field "Batch input only" (`XSYBL`) has been changed.

On GL Accounts you can check this by running the report `RFSABL00`.

Do you know any report like it for Document Types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes of SAP Master Data (like G/L accounts) and transaction data are logged automatically (and saved into tables CDHDR/CDPOS). However in this case, it is customizing data, where changes are logged (if at all) in a different way.

The setting is done on two levels:
Once, the change log has to be activated for the table:

> SE11 => Table T003 => Change => Technical settings

Here at the bottom of the screen, there is an option: Log changes. It has to be selected:

[image]

Second, the log change has to be activated on the client level as well:

> RZ11 => "rec/client" as profile parameter => set the value to ALL (for
> logging for all clients)

If this is done, the changes will be logged and you can report the changes with transaction SCU3.